# Events occuring

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A_1,....A_{20}$ be mutually independent events and let $p_i$ be there probabilities $(p_i = P(A_i))$ , $i  = 1,2,...,20$.

Express $Pr$(no events occuring) in terms of $p_1...p_{20}$

Express $Pr$(all events occurs) in terms of $p_1...p_{20}$

Express $Pr$(exactly one of the event occurs )in terms of $p_1...p_{20}$

I really got stuck on all three questions

Comment: Hint: The probability they all happen is $p_1p_2\cdots p_{20}$ (the product).

Comment: Your first two questions seem to be the same. The probability of the union is not the probability they all happen, all happen means intersection. And you formula for the probability of the union is not right.  Do check the exact wording of the three questions, and modify the post appropriately.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i got the answer but i don't know how to come to the answer ..

Comment: by the way i edited my question (the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $A_i$ does not happen is $1-p_i$.

Therefore by independence the probability that $A_1$ does not happen **and** $A_2$ doesn't happen and so on up to $A_{20}$ does not happen (that is, the probability that none of the $A_i$ happen) is
$$(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots (1-p_{20}).$$

By the way, though you seem not to have been asked this, the probability that **at least one** of the $A_i$ happens is therefore $1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots(1-p_{20})$.

The question about the probability all the $A_i$ happen is the simplest. The probability is, by independence, the product $p_1p_2\cdots p_{20}$.

For the probability of **exactly** one, note that the probability that $A_1$ happens and the others don't is $p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_3)\cdots(1-p_{20})$.

The probability that $A_1$ doesn't happen, but $A_2$ does, and the rest don't is 
$(1-p_1)p_2(1-p_3)\cdots (1-p_{20})$.

And so on, $20$ terms. The events described are pairwise disjoint, so the required probability is the sum.

One can make a simpler expression for this sum by letting $Q=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots (1-p_{20})$. If none of the $p_i$ is $1$, then the probability that exactly one of the $A_i$ happens is 
$$Q\left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}+\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}+\cdots +\frac{p_{20}}{1-p_{20}}\right).$$

Comment: how do u use the independece in question number 1 "...therefore by independence.." @AndreNicolas

Comment: If events $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_n$ are independent, then $\Pr(C_1)\cap C_2\cap\cdots \cap C_n)=\Pr(C_1)\Pr(C_2)\cdots \Pr(C_n)$. In (1) the $C_i$ are $A_i^c$.

Comment: but if as above $A_1...A_{20}$ is independent are their complement also independent $A_{1}^c...A_{20}^c$?

Comment: Yes, the complements are independent.